# I'm having trouble reading in characters from a file using strtok and fgets

Tags: c, pointers, fgets, strtok

I am reading a file that looks like this

00 READ 09

---

01 READ 10

and so on (the line in between represents a newline) but I can only get the first line for some reason. What am I doing wrong? It just prints 00 READ 09

Here's the code

```
int compile(FILE * fpointer)
{
   char string[12];
   char *tokenp = strtok(string, " ");

   while(fgets(string, sizeof(string), fpointer))
   {
      printf("%s" tokenp);
      tokenp = strtok(NULL, " \n");
   }
}
```

Comment: Try [this](https://ideone.com/acVNKl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running strtok on an unitialized string.

Comment: that's not the problem though because I used to have that line of code in the while loop and had !feof(fpointer) instead and it had the same problem. But I did try adding the fgets statement before the while loop and now it prints the second line and part of another one.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us the actual code that is causing you problems.  If what you do show is a bunch of crap that isn't related to your problem, your just wasting our time.

Comment: I mean the code you have is broken as I stated earlier.  Fix that and edit your question to reflect the new changes, then tell us what is still wrong with it.

Comment: Basically, your question is "What am I doing wrong?", so you've been told.

Comment: Not really, even when I run strtok on the initialized string I have the same problem essentially, as I said in my first comment.

Comment: @McLovinIt _That is the actual code_ `printf("%s" tokenp);` : It can not compile this line because the comma is forgotten. Therefore, this can not be the actual code.(Executing uncompileable code, said you can only get the first line.)

Comment: @McLovinIt, please see the guidance on writing a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).